# Closed form of a function $f(z)$ whose $\it{only}$ zeros are $n\pi$,$n\pi\omega$ and $n\pi\omega^2$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, functions, infinite-product

I need a closed form of  a function $f(z)$ whose $\it{only}$ zeros are $n\pi$,$n\pi \omega$ and $n\pi\omega^2 $ where $\omega$ is a cube root of unity and $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

So we need a function of type $$f(z)=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{z}{n\pi}\right) \left(1-\frac{z}{n\pi\omega}\right)  \left(1-\frac{z}{n\pi\omega^2}\right) $$

To find a closed form for above function we take logarithmic derivatives assuming $z$ which are not the points of zeros to get $$\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{z-n\pi}\right)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{z-n\pi\omega}\right)+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{z-n\pi\omega^2}\right) $$

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I am no expert so I doubt I could help much but maybe this could be helpful http://specialfunctionswiki.org/index.php/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem

Comment: A slight simplification is $\prod(1-\frac{z^3}{n^3\pi^3})$

Answer (score 6):

[Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) has no zeros and only simple poles in $0, -1,-2,-3, \ldots$ so $\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(1-\frac{z}{\pi}\right)}$ has only simple zeros at $\pi,2\pi,3\pi,\ldots$. Now this means that:

$$\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(1-\frac{z}{\pi}\right)\Gamma\left(1-\frac{z}{\omega\pi}\right)\Gamma\left(1-\frac{z}{\omega^2\pi}\right)}$$

is the function you are looking for.